# How do I add classes to the classpath for MBean Explorer in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jmx

I have a web app being deployed in JBoss AS 6.0.0. I'm using the JBoss Tools plugin in eclipse 3.6. I have the server configured with the project and it runs OK. My app exposes some MBeans via JMX.

I'm using the MBean Explorer view to access the JMX beans. Some of my beans return instances of classes defined in my project. When I invoke these methods via the explorer view I get a ClassNotFound exception for these classes.

How can I add my classes to the classpath for the MBean Explorer view?

(If it easier to do this with eclipse-jmx plugin, I'm happy to use that instead.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to implement your jmx beans using open types.  then you won't have problems like this.  this problem will repeat itself if you try to use any other tools to interact with your mbeans.  best practice with mbeans is to stick to open types so you don't have to worry about client-side issues.

Comment: Yeah I know it would be nice to use only standard library classes or primatives for my return types, but unfortunately my requirements dictate that I must return, for example, Lists of detailed events, each with many fields. I guess jamming all the fields of each object into a Map would be least worst way to do this, but I don't want to. For what it's worth by giving a simple classpath argument to jconsole for example, I can achieve what I'm trying to do fine, it would just be convenient to achieve the same within eclipse.